# Kextload fails on macOS Sierra. ( FTDIUSBSerialDriver failed to load)

Tags: macos, ftdi, kernel-extension

I'm trying to work with a FT232H board. I installed the drivers from the FTDI webpage. Both the FTDIUSBSerialDriver and the D2XX Helper Driver. 
On running kextstat I don't see any anything with FTDI in it. I thought the kext wasn't loaded. When I tried to run "kextload -b /Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext I got this as the output

```
FTDIUSBSerialDriver failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

Same result on trying to load the AppleFTDI kext.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does kextutil say?

Comment: @awiebe "Can't find extension with identifier FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/."

Comment: Are you sure it didn't just get deleted?
what is the output of
`ls -l /Library/Extensions/ | grep "USB"`

Comment: @awiebe Nope `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Feb  1 12:34 FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext`

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying the "-b" flag to the command. This changes kextload to expect the kext's bundle identifier, not its path. Leave off the -b and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite complicated but I've found an article regarding the matter of all the setup, such as why your driver may have been unloaded in the first place.

http://dfusion.com.au/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+FTDI+USB+Serial+Driver+on+Mac

In the info plist somewhere there should be

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver</string>
```

In your load command **specify this identifier instead of the file path**.

Comment: Did not get you. Where'd you get the *identifier*? I went to HoRNDIS-Info.plist file but couldn't find anything.